# How to call a variable by referencing in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, reference

I have a method on a JavaScript object with the structure:

```
performOperation: function (rel) {
    var currentArray = [];

    switch (rel) {
        case 'templates':
            currentArray = templates;
        break;

        case 'drafts':
            currentArray = drafts;
        break;

        case 'sent':
            currentArray = sent;
        break;

        case 'scheduled':
            currentArray = scheduled;
        break;

        case 'cancelled':
            currentArray = cancelled;
        break;

        case 'inbox':
            currentArray = inbox;
        break;
    }

    // Series of operations here.

    switch (rel) {
        case 'templates':
            templates = currentArray;
        break;

        case 'drafts':
            drafts = currentArray;
        break;

        case 'sent':
            sent = currentArray;
        break;

        case 'scheduled':
            scheduled = currentArray;
        break;

        case 'cancelled':
            cancelled = currentArray;
        break;

        case 'inbox':
            inbox = currentArray;
        break;
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can call this `var currentArray` by referencing the array to be used i.e. either `drafts, inbox, cancelled, ...`. In C++ and PHP I know we do referencing by using the `&` before the variable.

If there is any way to do this referencing in JavaScript, please all answers are welcomed.

Comment: There is no call-by-reference in JavaScript. No way.

Comment: If you are *manipulating* an object, such as one of your arrays, you don't have to write it back, as you've never created a copy of it. Objects are reference values.

Comment: You really want to use an object and reference its properties by dynamic names, instead of holding a bunch of different variables together.

Answer (score 0):

You may change the data structure to an object, which have the wanted properties for the access, you describe.

```
var data = {
        templates: [],
        drafts: [],
        sent: [],
        scheduled: [],
        cancelled: [],
        inbox: []
    };

function performOperation(rel) {
    var currentArray = data[rel];
    //
    // Series of operations here.
    //
    data[rel] = currentArray;
}
```